# changing chapter number and first letter font size

Tags: fonts

i have requirements for a document given by somebodu who prefers to use Word.
The requirementis following:

> A table of contents should appear before the introduction. Please indicate the page numbers.
>   Chapters should commence on a right-hand, odd numbered, page. The chapter title should be set in
>   bold type in 18 point capitals, using 24 point capitals for initial letters and the chapter number, and
>   ranged left.

How can I make my chapter titles start with number and first letter sized 24pt?

Comment: You may achieve something similar by using 24 pt small capitals and set the first letter in upper case. I would have started with KOMA-script, which make this simple (just look at the `addtokomafont` command in the manual). Also, `memoir` makes this pretty simple, but you have to start reading the manual and provide us with an MWE.

Answer (score 2):

You may achieve something similar by using 24 pt small capitals and set the first letter in upper case. I have used `\Huge`, which is a little less than 24 with `11 pt` main font. You may replace `\Huge` with `\fontsize{24pt}{28.8pt}`. I recommend you to start with [KOMA-script](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script), which make this simple (just look at the `\addtokomafont` command in the manual). Also, [memoir](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir) makes this pretty simple

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\setkomafont{section}{\normalfont}
\addtokomafont{section}{\Huge\scshape}

\begin{document}

\section{This is an ugly heading}

Here is the text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

To make the headings less ugly, add the packages `lmodern`and `mictotype`

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern} % scalable font
\usepackage{microtype} % microtypography
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\setkomafont{section}{\normalfont}
\addtokomafont{section}{\fontsize{24pt}{28.8pt}\selectfont\scshape\textls}

\begin{document}

\section{This is a less ugly heading}

Here is the text.

\end{document}
```

[image]